# How to colour a matplotlib histogram by values in another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

I create a dataframe using

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df_dict = {
    "test_predictions": [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9],
    "y_true": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    "distance" : [-0.1, -0.09, -0.08, -0.08, -0.07, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.03, -0.02, -0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

I then make a plot that consists of two straight line plots and a histogram using

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color="red", linestyle=":", label="Perfect Model")
ax1.plot(df['test_predictions'], df['y_true'], label="NN3", color='blue')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.hist(df['test_predictions'], bins=10, alpha=0.7, color='darkgreen', label='Histogram')
```

I would like to color the histogram based on the values in `df['distance']` and also include a colormap. So essentially it is possible for there to be multiple colors in one bin of the histogram. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

I tried doing this prior to `ax2.hist(df['test_predictions'], bins=10, alpha=0.7, color='darkgreen', label='Histogram')`

```
bins = np.linspace(df['test_predictions'].min(), df['test_predictions'].max(), 10)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    bin_index = np.digitize(row['test_predictions'], bins)
    color = plt.cm.viridis(row['distance']/df['distance'].max())
    ax2.bar(bins[bin_index-1], 1, width=np.diff(bins)[0], color = color, alpha  = 0.7)
```

However, i'm worried about the fact that I use a for loop because my actual dataframe could contain over 10000 rows and also I don't get the desired output when I do this, it comes out like individual bars instead of stacked like a histogram.

Comment: Have you looked at the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/hist.html#updating-histogram-colors)?

Comment: @importrandom yes, I tried to do something similar to what they do in the for loop of the updating histogram colors section, but I found that I could only update the color of one bar at a time. Whereas in my case, because I am colouring based on the values in another column, I could have multiple colors in one bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The example data from the post

You could use `imshow` on the distance values that belong to each bar.

The code below first creates an extra dataframe column with the bin ids of each row. Then, the distances for each bin are selected, and used as input for `imshow()`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_dict = {
    "test_predictions": [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9],
    "y_true": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    "distance": [-0.1, -0.09, -0.08, -0.08, -0.07, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.04, -0.04, -0.04, -0.03, -0.02, -0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=df['distance'].min(), vmax=df['distance'].max())

num_bins = 10
bins = np.linspace(df['test_predictions'].min(), df['test_predictions'].max() + 0.001, num_bins + 1)
df['bin'] = np.digitize(df['test_predictions'], bins)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
for bin_id, bin_df in df.groupby('bin'):
    ax1.imshow(bin_df['distance'].values. Reshape(-1, 1), interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
               extent=[bins[bin_id - 1], bins[bin_id], 0, len(bin_df)], aspect='auto')

ax1.use_sticky_edges = False # remove stickiness due to imshow
ax1.autoscale_view()
ax1.set_ylim(ymin=0)

plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), label='Distance', ax=ax1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib histogram with bars colored via other column]

## The 'tips' dataset

Here is another example, with the 'tips' dataset from Seaborn.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import seaborn as sns  # to get the 'tips' dataset
import numpy as np

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
df.sort_values(by='tip', ascending=True, inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r')
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=df['tip'].min(), vmax=df['tip'].max())

num_bins = 10
bins = np.linspace(df['total_bill'].min(), df['total_bill'].max() + 0.001, num_bins + 1)
df['bin'] = np.digitize(df['total_bill'], bins)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
for bin_id, bin_df in df.groupby('bin'):
    ax1.imshow(bin_df['tip'].values. Reshape(-1, 1), interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
               extent=[bins[bin_id - 1], bins[bin_id], 0, len(bin_df)], aspect='auto')

ax1.use_sticky_edges = False  # remove stickiness due to imshow
ax1.autoscale_view()
ax1.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax1.set_xlabel('Total Bill')
ax1.set_ylabel('Count')

plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), label='Tip', ax=ax1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: coloring histogram of total_bill by tip amount]